# Build Mono on Embedded Linux (ARM7)

Tags: embedded, arm

I configure mono with the command below

```
./configure --host=arm-linux --build=arm-none-linux-gnueabi --target=arm-linux --cache-file=arm-linux.cache --disable-mcs-build
```

the file arm-linux.cache is

```
mono_cv_clang=no
mono_cv_uscore=no
with_tls=no
with_sigaltstack=no
```

And I when i make the mono, the error message is:

> In file included from mini-arch.h:21,
>                        from mini.h:35,
>                        from genmdesc.c:9:
>       mini-arm.h:39:2: error: #error "At least one of ARM_FPU_NONE, ARM_FPU_FPA, ARM_FPU_VFP or ARM_FPU_VFP_HARD must be defined."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to define/select one of the `floating point hardware` options for the target you have, example:

```
make CFLAGS=-DARM_FPU_NONE
```

Comment: Thanks. I have passed the problem.

Comment: @Ghost you're welcome, if that solved your problem you should accept the answer, if not then answer your own question and accept it.